# unknown country and unknown region in Sitecore Experience Analytics

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I did a "roll my own" implementation of Geo IP Location, instead of paying for the Sitecore one.

My data is getting recorded.  I can see it under each contacts profile details.

But when I go into the Experience Analytics Dashboard > Audience > Locations the Country and Region show only [unknown country] and [unknown region]

The city is filled out just fine.

I am guessing this is because country and region are being expected in some specific format.

Here we see country *is recorded* for contacts.
[image: Country is recorded]

But here, we see that all countries show up as unknown.
[image: All countries shown up as unknown]

---

UPDATE: This is my implementation code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Net;


namespace MySite.Analytics
{
    public class IPLookupProvider : LookupProviderBase
    {
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public override WhoIsInformation GetInformationByIp(string ipAddress)
        {
            WhoIsInformation whois = new WhoIsInformation();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Location.IsPrivateIP(ipAddress) == false)
                    {

                        Uri geoLocationServiceUrl = new Uri("https://freegeoip.net/json/" + ipAddress);
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                        var serviceResponse = client.DownloadString(geoLocationServiceUrl);
                        dynamic serviceData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serviceResponse);

                        whois.City = serviceData.city ?? string.Empty;
                        whois.MetroCode = serviceData.metro_code.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                        whois.Region = serviceData.region_name ?? string.Empty;
                        whois.PostalCode = serviceData.zip_code ?? string.Empty;
                        whois.Country = serviceData.country_name ?? string.Empty;
                        whois.Latitude = serviceData.latitude ?? 0;
                        whois.Longitude = serviceData.longitude ?? 0;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error("JDA.Analytics.IPLookupProvider.GetInformationByIp: " + ex.StackTrace.ToString(), ex, "Location");
                }
            }
            return whois;
        }
    }
}
```

And my patch file:

```
<lookupManager>
    <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">custom</patch:attribute>
    <providers>
        <add name="custom" type="MySite.Analytics.IPLookupProvider, MySite.Analytics"/>
    </providers>
</lookupManager>
```

When I look in Mongo it appears that all the Country, Region, etc. fields are 
"N/A".   But if I look at the details for the Contact they are populated.

Comment: Hey, can you post what you have saved against the contacts in mongo's geoip collection. I believe you need to save the country code in "Country" property and that should an item in: /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Lookups/Countries

Comment: I was using the country and region name instead of the "code".   I updated , and it appears that it may be working now.   I will know more tomorrow once more data is populated.

Comment: This was the trick!   By using @dnstommy example and using the country and region codes instead of the names resulted in a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my roll you own provider. I have tested this in 8.0 and 8.1.

```
   public class IPLookupProvider : LookupProviderBase
    {
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public override WhoIsInformation GetInformationByIp(string ip)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(ip, "ip");
            WhoIsInformation whoIsInformation = new WhoIsInformation();

            Log.Info("Looking up IP " + ip, "WhoIsInformation");

            try
            {
                string text = RequestIPData(ip);
                var matchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, "(?<=^|,)(\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\"|[^,]*)");

                if (text.IndexOf("IP_NOT_FOUND", StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
                {
                    return ContactLocation.CreateUnknown();
                }


                string[] array = kickfireFormat.Split(',');
                if (matchCollection.Count == 0)
                {

                    throw new Exception("Unexpected format. Cannot parse the IP lookup response for IP address: {0}{1}{2}".FormatWith(ip, Environment.NewLine, text));
                }

                Log.Info("IP info is " + text, "WhoIsInformation");

                var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IpLookup.RootObject>(text);

                if (model != null
                    && model.status == "success")
                {
                    double latitude = 0;
                    double longitude = 0;

                    whoIsInformation.BusinessName = model.data.name;
                    whoIsInformation.City = model.data.city;
                    whoIsInformation.Country = model.data.country;
                    double.TryParse(model.data.latitude, out latitude);
                    double.TryParse(model.data.longitude, out longitude);

                    whoIsInformation.Latitude = latitude;
                    whoIsInformation.Longitude = longitude;

                    whoIsInformation.Region = model.data.region;

                }

                Log.Info("Model was successful." + whoIsInformation.BusinessName + "-" + whoIsInformation.City, "WhoIsInformation");

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logging.Helpers.Logging.LogError(exception.StackTrace, exception);
            }
            return whoIsInformation;
        }
```

The RequestIP data looks like this

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "result":1,
   "data":{  
      "name":"Vodafone GmbH",
      "city":"Disteln",
      "region":"Nordrhein-Westfalen",
      "countryShort":"DE",
      "country":"Germany",
      "latitude":"51.606010",
      "longitude":"7.149110"
   }
}
```

Config

```
  <sitecore>
    <lookupManager>
      <x:attribute name="defaultProvider">bonfire</x:attribute>
      <providers>
        <add name="bonfire" type="YourApp.IPLookupProvider, YourApp"/>
      </providers>
    </lookupManager>
  </sitecore>
```

Also have you looking in Mongo to see if you country is there and valid? Its in the GeoIP table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into this when I am back in the office on Thursday

Comment: You will see my update above.   Still not working.  I noticed in your code you push the "country" attribute.   But in your GeoIP your data looks like "countryShort".

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nope.  Implemented the suggested changes with no change.  :(

Comment: By using this example AND using the country and region codes (as josedbaez suggested) instead of the names I now have a working solution.

Comment: Great! Are you using the short country code in region and country? Or are you using a short region code too?

Comment: Short codes in both... i.e. CA for California, US for United States